# Stackoverflow exception - multiple calculation

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

So I am working on a problem from Project Euler where I have to find a smallest multiple of a certain number.

Currently it is working code for a starting number of 10 **but** when I input 20, I get a stackoverflow exception. I cannot seem to figure out what it is I am doing wrong.

```
public class MultipleCalculator
{
    public static int StartingNumber { get; } = 0;
    private int MultipleCypher = 20;
    public bool MultipleFound = false;

    public MultipleCalculator(int multipleCypher)
    {
    }

    public int FindSmallestMultiple()
    {
        return FindMultiple(MultipleCypher);
    }

    private int FindMultiple(int startingNumberOfSequence)
    {
        while (!MultipleFound)
        {
            var isMultiple = IsMultiple(startingNumberOfSequence);
            if (isMultiple)
            {
                MultipleFound = true;
                return startingNumberOfSequence;
            }
            startingNumberOfSequence += MultipleCypher;
            return FindMultiple(startingNumberOfSequence);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private bool IsMultiple(int startingNumberOfSequence)
    {
        var dividableNumber = MultipleCypher - 1;

        while (dividableNumber > 0)
        {
            if ((startingNumberOfSequence % dividableNumber) == 0)
                dividableNumber--;
            else
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you get stackoverflow exception because you are calling your function recursively.

Refactor your code to remove the recursion.

Comment: Indeed, I could have omitted the recursion. This removal of the recursion fixed the problem. I don't see why I didn't even see this, many thanks! I will accept this answer when stackoverflow allows me to.